# android progress dialog doesn't show percent

Tags: android, progressdialog

Dialog doesn't show me percent If I've used code

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int total = msg.arg1;
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(total);
        if (total >= 100){
            try {
                mProgressThread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            mProgressThread.setState(ProgressThread.STATE_DONE);
        }
    }
};
```

and in thread code

```
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                msg.arg1 = total;
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
```

What's wrong? If I use total++; instead total +=count; the scale raise to 19 percent but doesn't raise to 100%. It is because the file is download faster than the while loop 100 iteration.
If I use total += count; It shows 0 but the the scale is on 100% the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You seem not to pass any percentage information to the handler but the total absolute number of read characters. When you write total++; you pass the number of of times your read routine receives data and when you write total +=count; you pass the total number of all characters you read in during your complete read routine.

If you want to show percentages you need to pass in the progress from 0-100. To do this you need to know how many characters you will read in total and write total +=count; and pass total/CountOfAllCharactersToRead. This way you will properly ass the %-fraction to the proress dialog.

Just a another comment. If your reading routine is very fast it can happen that the UI does not update frequently and you will not see the progress bar actually running from 0 to 100.

Comment: If I use int fileLength = con.getContentLength();
And use ((total*100)/fileLength) It doesn't work correctly